# How to make python await for "nothing", running the event loop first

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

I run a python program which is run by network events and cannot go 10-15 seconds without processing heartbeats. (More specifically, I use discord.py with a pretty large volume of events)

In one of the possible scenarios I could have a command store a large amount of data into a database, this could potentially take up more than those 10 to 15 seconds, and is blocking.

These are thousands of small database calls where I could make the asynchronous event loop "run its course" in between those calls if needed. How can I make python "`await` for nothing" in this case?

A similair hack would be to await for a resolved `Promise` in JavaScript, which throws the process back into the event loop, resolving more pressing events first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`await asyncio.sleep(0)` - [is a way](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/284) to return control to an event loop.

Although instead of constantly calling it you may go another way: run your blocking code [in another thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) using `run_in_executor` and awaiting for it to be finished. This way event loop will normally continue it's course while blocking stuff being processed in background thread.